# When exporting as .FBX, I don't have the option "include animation" that I've seen in tutorials

Tags: animation, interface, export

I've been working at this for a while now and have uninstalled and reinstalled Blender.  Is it possible that I haven't animated properly and the export menu is contextual?  I set my key frames, and it animates in the 3D view and the transformation appears in the graph editor.  If more information is needed, I can supply it.

I'm sure there is something very obvious I'm missing.

[image: Screen-grab]

Answer (score 2):

The following settings work for me with bridging Blender/UE4 but they may differ from engine to engine.

Use 'Armature + Mesh' to transfer the model and its associated rigging.

Use 'Armature' only to transfer subsequent animations.

Be sure to uncheck 'Add Leaf Bones' for UE4.  Other Engines may work best with this option activated.  A bit of trial and error should get you through that part.

Carefully go through the game engine created model/animation directory for what you imported and verify each new file to make sure they should be there, delete whatever mistakes happen from the transfer process.

[image]

[image]

If you happen to be using UE4, there is a video playlist published by Epic that shows how to handle these things on their end.

More info on the topic can be found using the following keywords:
"Unreal Engine, Youtube, Zak Parrish, Getting Started: Introduction to Blueprint 3rd Person Game Creation"

Here's a link to the playlist

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZlv_N0_O1gZS5HylO_368myr-Kg2ZLwb

Comment: Thank you!  It didn't answer my question as to where that checkbox was, but this method is working perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Your tutorials were probably using old (deprecated but sometimes still useful) FBX 6.1 ASCII exporter (you can still use it by changing setting in the top **Version:** dropdown menu).

In new 7.4 binary FBX exporter, the matching option is called **Baked Animation**, and which animation(s) are baked/exported is then controlled by the two next checkboxes (disable both if you only want the current scene’s animation).